# Cannot Clone private GIT Repo on FileShare using VS Code

Tags: git, version-control

I have created a private GIT Repository on a remote FileShare
\dc\Engineering\Software Development\Git Repository\abreldashRepo
I am able to make changes using VS Code, Commit and push them to this repo with no issues.

I have been trying to clone this repo using VS Code on a 2nd computer.

In VS Code I get the following error

> git clone %5C%5Cdc%5CEngineering%5CSoftware%20Development%5CGit%20Repository%5CabreldashRepo c:\Development\NiallODwyer\TESTGITREPODASH\abreldashRepo --progress [90ms]
> 2023-11-07 16:28:40.910 [info] fatal: repository '%5C%5Cdc%5CEngineering%5CSoftware%20Development%5CGit%20Repository%5CabreldashRepo' does not exist

I have checked the permissions and given the user full access to the fileshare folder on the 2nd computer.
The repo was created using the command
git init --bare
Also I tried the folloiw
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/main